# How to give two different Drawer items for two different components in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I have a scenario where there is an anonymous drawer which consists of All books and a logged in user Drawer which consists of My books & all books. I have a Drawer Route Navigation file which consists of the drawer navigation. how can I  reuse the same navigation for both the scenarios? I also have to pass the user Id.

Answer (score 0):

Have a generic function to which you will pass data of that drawer item like this:

```
drawerItem(drawerICon, drawerText, drawerItemNavigation){
     return (
            <View>Your drawer code here</View>
     )
}
```

Call your function with logged in check from main render function like this:

```
render(){
     return(  
          <View>
            ......
            {
            this.props.user.logged_in
            &&
           this.drawerItem(iconsrc, "Home", "profile")
           }
           ....
      )
```

if you want to learn more about conditional rendering please have visit on [this resource](https://medium.com/@szholdiyarov/conditional-rendering-in-react-native-286351816db4)